# Не могу разобраться, что такое класс объекта DTO. Буду очень благодарна за простой пример

Tags: java, dto

Нужно написать метод реализующий некую функцию возвращающую объект DTO. Нашла много однотипных объяснений что это, но простых примеров нет.

Comment: Если объяснение в том вопросе выглядит недостаточно простым, то будет лучше, если вы попробуете спросить конкретные непонятные места (из того объяснения)